# Swift - animate linear diagram with minimal segment

Tags: ios, swift

I have a linear diagram view which basically is nothing but three views. They represent the percentage of certain asset in a portfolio. So, when I click a button, I call `update(multipliers: [CGFloat])` and the animation starts. However, I ran into a few issues. Imagine if I have $10000 in stocks, $5000 in bonds and $1 in ETFs. The ETF view won't be visible at all because it's so small. But even in this case I want to show a 10px or something width view. How can I achieve this? Also, my debugger keeps warning me

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.     Probably at least one
> of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.

which is understandable, but I don't think is fixable because of multipliers and constants not matching the width.

So, how can I solve the issue?

```
import UIKit

class StripView: UIView {
    
    var stocksConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()
    var bondsConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()
    var etfConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()
    
    let stocksView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 4
        return view
    }()
    
    let bondsView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 4
        return view
    }()
    
    let etfView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 4
        return view
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        backgroundColor = .clear
        layer.cornerRadius = 4
        layer.masksToBounds = true
        
        setupViews()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func update(multipliers: [CGFloat]) {
        stocksView.removeConstraint(stocksConstraint)
        stocksConstraint = stocksView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: multipliers[0])
        stocksConstraint.isActive = true
                
        bondsView.removeConstraint(bondsConstraint)
        bondsConstraint = bondsView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: multipliers[1])
        bondsConstraint.isActive = true
        
        
        etfView.removeConstraint(etfConstraint)
        etfConstraint = etfView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: multipliers[2])
        etfConstraint.isActive = true
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
            
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
            
            self.stocksView.backgroundColor = .systemRed
            self.bondsView.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
            self.etfView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
            
        }
        
    }
    
    func setupViews() {
        
        let views = [stocksView, bondsView, etfView]
        
        views.forEach {
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            addSubview($0)
        }
        
        stocksConstraint = stocksView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.33)
        bondsConstraint = bondsView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.33)
        etfConstraint = etfView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.33)
        
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stocksView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            stocksView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            stocksView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            stocksConstraint,
            
            bondsView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            bondsView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            bondsView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stocksView.trailingAnchor, constant: 2),
            bondsConstraint,
            
            etfView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            etfView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            etfView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bondsView.trailingAnchor, constant: 2),
            etfConstraint
        ])
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to set constraits?

Comment: "but I don't think is fixable"  What is fixable?